# Start Quartz Scheduler using linux shell script

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler

I am using Quartz plugin in Grails and it works fine, the job start on the 1th day of every month, see my code below. 
Now I would like to start the job using linux shell script (script.sh). is that possible? and how to do that? please with example. Thanks

```
static triggers = {
      cron name: 'myJobTrigger', cronExpression: '0 00 09 01 * ?' // Fire at 09:00am on the 1th day of every month
    }
```

Comment: their two different things. You could create a controller action that triggers a task given certain things that make it robust or if it is internal just call controller action that then triggers quartz job. Then write a cron schedule under linux that calls a shell script that executes wget or curl to the url of controller

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer on my question, its possible agreed with Quartz documantion, see link below:

[Cron-based Triggers](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/generated/2.2.2/html/qtz-all/#page/quartz-scheduler-webhelp%2Fre-exp_example3.html%23)